# Asp.net, html, incorrect output via asp (server-side)

Tags: asp.net, html

I was trying to output some HTML code and got weird output,
This is the string i print this code in client-side
        `<form runat="server">
        <%=buttons%>
        </form>`

and server side is(ofcourse the buttons is a public string)

```
buttons = "<asp:Button id='loggin' runat=\"server\" text=\"התחבר\" onclick='loggin_Click'></asp:button>";`
```

the html code looks like [this](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/2136/problemyb.png).
I print this string using this code : `<%= buttons%>`, And this is the out put i get: [Link](http://s8.postimg.org/by4f9paph/Capture.png). if anyone have any idea about what could go wrong i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Comment: <div class="main" style="padding: 0 0 0 0">
<%=name%>
<%= buttons%>          
</div>             if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            name = "" + Session["user"];
            buttons = "<button id='logout' onclick='logouta()'>התנתק</button>";
        }
        else
        {
            name = "<span style='float:right;'>שלום אורח</span>";
            buttons = "<asp:button id='regb' runat='server' text='הרשם' onclick='reg_Click'></asp:Button> <asp:Button id='loggin' runat='server' text='התחבר' onclick='loggin_Click'></asp:button>";
            
        }

Comment: Can you update your question to show context of the code - more code around it ;)

Comment: im having a problem of clicking enter i have to go now ill add more code when ill comeback

Comment: edited and thank you for the fast reply

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding which part of the code is where and the process that connects them. Can you post (in your question) rendered html code - what you get in the browser, and relevant portion of your `.aspx` file?

Comment: added. im sorry its isnt understanable but im trying my best to do it understandable. and again thanks for the fast reply

Comment: What is your question? What results are you expecting? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i expect the code to write what ever in the text="" to be in the buttons and i will be able to click on that button                            im doing it just because i want to transfer button click to server side, if you got anything else i would like to know